# Issue in deploying Spring application on jboss

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I need to deploy me web application on jboss server. For this, I have placed the war file in the jboss deployment directory and starting the jboss.

My war structure is:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/
WEB-INF/classes/com/
WEB-INF/classes/com/tutorialspoint/
WEB-INF/classes/com/tutorialspoint/ClassList.class
WEB-INF/classes/com/tutorialspoint/DTEJob.class
WEB-INF/classes/com/tutorialspoint/DbAccess.class
WEB-INF/classes/com/tutorialspoint/HelloController.class
WEB-INF/classes/com/tutorialspoint/LabelInfo.class
WEB-INF/classes/com/tutorialspoint/UserInfo.class
WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml
WEB-INF/jsp/
WEB-INF/jsp/DTECommand.jsp
WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp
WEB-INF/lib/
WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-2.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/javax.validation-1.0.0.GA.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jdbc-oracle.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jquery-1.11.1.js
WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc14.jar
WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-aspects-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-aspects-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-aspects-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-build-src-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-support-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-support-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-support-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-instrument-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-instrument-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-instrument-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-jms-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-jms-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-jms-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-oxm-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-oxm-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-oxm-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-struts-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-struts-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-struts-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/standard.jar
WEB-INF/web.xml
```

jBoss Error:

```
03:44:51,014 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context initialization failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.customizeBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:218) [org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE-A]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) [org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE-A]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465) [org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE-A]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395) [org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE-A]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272) [org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE-A]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196) [org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE-A]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE-A]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
```

Kindly suggest what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `spring-aop`module is missing (looks like you're bundling sources and javadnc in there!). Besides, please update especially if you're running on a recent JBoss version.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove all the spring 3.0.1 jars to make it workable.